# How to execute the tar file without any error?

Tags: command-line

```
tar (child): ushare-11a-netou.tar.bz2: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Comment: `Cannot open: No such file or directory`: are you certain that the tar file is present in the directory? Perhaps you are running the command from a different location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be having a problem because a tar.bz2 is not the same as a tar.gz, first, you need to extract the file into it's own folder, and compile it, then you can install it. As I am slightly unfamiliar with this process, having only needed to do it once, I will link you to the page that helped me.

[How do I install a .tar.gz (or .tar.bz2) file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-do-i-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file)